# alloc/init and the setting of instance variables

Tags: objective-c, initialization, allocation

It is my understanding that, in addition to allocating memory, `alloc` sets all instance variables (with the exception of the `isa` variable) to zero or to the equivalent type for zero, such as `nil`, `NULL`, and `0.0.`

But I recently read the following about `init:`

> Initialization sets the instance
>   variables of an object to reasonable
>   and useful initial values.

I'm a bit confused as to what "reasonable and useful initial values" means....

If `alloc` has already set the values to zero, is `init` altering these values in any way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If alloc has already set the values to zero, is init altering these values in any way?

Sure.

For example, you may have an object that represents a rectangle with ivars to represent width and height; in `init` you may initialize these ivars to some sane default, say 300x200.

That's all they're talking about.

If you're asking whether NSObject's `-init` method is initializing the values of your subclass's ivars to some non-zero values, the answer of course is no.

Comment: So the quote that I read was referring to *convenience* initializers and not NSObject's -init.

That's exactly what I wanted to know...Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is entirely possible. For example, a data structure may have member variables that require dynamic memory be allocated and initialized as well. The `alloc` call will reserve the space for the member variables and the `init` call will make those values useful (e.g., suballocation & initialization).

`alloc` and `init` are separate because you can have multiple `init` routines for a class that initialize an object in differing ways.

You can also call `alloc` and `init` at the same time by calling `new`. Thus the following two lines are equivalent:

```
[[NSObject alloc] init];
[NSObject new];
```